# Windows Server 2019 not updating after restoring recent snapshot

Tags: windows, wsus, windows-server-2019

I'm facing an issue regarding the Windows Server 2019 update.

I have recently restored the Windows Server with a recent snapshot. Every time I install a Windows Update it's **undoing changes**,
this is the error code list in event viewer `0x800f0922`.

Note: I'm installing updates through a WSUS server

Answer (score 0):

you might try stopping the windows update services and removing the update cache. On the server in question, open an elevated command prompt (run as admin) and enter the following:

```
net stop wuauserv
del /s /q C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download
del /s /q C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore\DataStore.edb
net start wuauserv
```

Once this is done, reboot and attempt installing updates again. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Andy 

The issue still persists. I have download the 'KB5003638' manually from the windows catalog and try to install still its undoing the changes